# What is the exact source of this hadeeth?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I have found this hadeeth:

> Anas bin Malik (RA) narrates that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: " I
>   wish that I could meet my brothers." The Sahaabah (RAA) asked: "Aren't
>   we your brothers?" He replied: "You are my Companions, but my brothers
>   are those who will believe in me without having seen me

It is supposed to be in Saheeh Muslim(?). I have the kutubus-sitta (arabic) but cannot seem to trace this.

Would it be possible to quote the exact reference to this hadith with number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadith occurs in [Sahih Muslim (249)](http://sunnah.com/muslim/2/51) in the Book of Taharah, Chapter on Making the Limbs Glow by Wudu:

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَتَى الْمَقْبُرَةَ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ السَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكُمْ دَارَ قَوْمٍ مُؤْمِنِينَ وَإِنَّا إِنْ شَاءَ اللَّهُ بِكُمْ لاَحِقُونَ وَدِدْتُ أَنَّا قَدْ رَأَيْنَا إِخْوَانَنَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالُوا أَوَلَسْنَا إِخْوَانَكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَنْتُمْ أَصْحَابِي وَإِخْوَانُنَا الَّذِينَ لَمْ يَأْتُوا بَعْدُ ‏"‏ ‏ ...

It [also occurs](http://sunnah.com/search/%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%AF%D8%AA-%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%A7-%D9%82%D8%AF-%D8%B1%D8%A3%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7-%D8%A5%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%86%D8%A7) in Sunan Ibn Majah and Sunan an-Nasa'i.